# Alignment and dotfill in 3-column longtable

Tags: tables, longtable, alignment

I am trying to create a 6.5in `longtable` with 3 columns (Name, Major/University, Date). I would like the first and second cells to be left-aligned, while the third cell is right-aligned. I want to use `\dotfill` between the cells.

I am still new to customizing the parameters in tables, but this is what I have now. **As can be seen, there is a space between the dots in the 2nd and 3rd cell for each row. I would like it if I could close this gap, and I'm not sure how.** I tried putting `@{}` after the `>{\dotfill\raggedleft\arraybackslash}` but that raised an error.

Here is a MWE and picture of output.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{1.625in}<{\dotfill}@{}p{3.875in}<{\dotfill}@{}@{}>{\dotfill\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1in}@{}}

        First Last & Some Thing and Some Thing, Some Where and Some Where & 2019 \\
        FirstFirst LastLast & Some Thing and Some Other Thing, Some Where, Somewhere & 2019 \\
        FirstFirst Last & Something, Somewhere & 2018 - 2019 \\
        First LastLast & Something Something, Somewhere Somewhere & Fall 2019 \\
        First Middle Last & Thing, Where & Summer 2019 \\
        First Middle Middle Last & Something, Where & Spring 2019 \\
        First Last & Something Some Other Thing, Somewhere and Somewhere & Winter 2019 \\

    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE code. There is a gap between the dotfills of the 2nd and 3rd cell for each row.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

simpler to use two columns:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

% not around longtable \begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}p{1.625in}<{\dotfill}@{}p{4.875in}@{}}

        First Last & Some Thing and Some Thing, Some Where and Some Where \dotfill 2019 \\
        FirstFirst LastLast & Some Thing and Some Other Thing, Some Where, Somewhere \dotfill 2019 \\
        FirstFirst Last & Something, Somewhere \dotfill 2018 - 2019 \\
        First LastLast & Something Something, Somewhere Somewhere \dotfill Fall 2019 \\
        First Middle Last & Thing, Where \dotfill Summer 2019 \\
        First Middle Middle Last & Something, Where \dotfill Spring 2019 \\
        First Last & Something Some Other Thing, Somewhere and Somewhere \dotfill Winter 2019 \\

    \end{longtable}
% \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this is a good workaround, I have to manually put the `\dotfill`s in the table content, which I don't want to do. How can I solve this without using `\dotfill` in the table content?

Comment: @Abraham, In your question title you require to have `\dotfill`. If you not liked, than just remove them from  table specification in your MWE.

Comment: @Abraham I don't see it as any different really, in your suggested markup you manually separate by `&` and here I separate by `\dotfill` it's just a single tex token in either case. In practice I would use `\newcommand\myrow[3]{#1&#2\dotfill#3\\}` and then `\myrow{foo}{bar}{2019}`  which you could do whatever underlying syntax is used.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good idea to use a `\newcommand` for this purpose, that helps! Thanks, I'll mark this as the accepted answer :)